# Graphene-Django: How to append an error from middleware without actually raising an error

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'd like to create some Graphene middleware where if:

- The client has sent an auth token header
- The server has not found a valid authenticated user for this token

the server will raise an error so that the client can decide to smoothly log the user out.

I can easily do this using something like:

```
def graphql_auth_check(next, root, info, **args):
    auth_header = info.context.request.headers.get('Authorization')

    if (auth_header and not info.context.user.is_authenticated):
        raise GraphQLError('Client sent an auth header but user was not authenticated')

    return next(root, info, **args)
```

However, I'd like the graphQL request data to still be honoured as much as possible, whereas the above would return `data: null`.

Is there a way of simply "appending" an error without having to block the whole field resolution flow?

Comment: Hi did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
# utils.py
import jwt
from graphql import GraphQLError
from graphql_jwt.utils import jwt_decode
 
def customized_jwt_decode(token, context=None):
    try:
        payload = jwt_decode(token, context)
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        do something when token expired
    except jwt.DecodeError or jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        do something when token is invalid
    return payload
 
 
# settings.py
 
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER': 'app.utils.customized_jwt_decode',  # path to your customized_jwt_decode
}
```